# Suggested tag synonym queue with very old suggestions

Tags: discussion, support, tag-synonyms

When I checked suggested tag synonyms queue, I saw very old suggestions

[image]

Only [django](/questions/tagged/django) « [django-orm](/questions/tagged/django-orm) is a correct suggestion. Rest are all invalid and [django](/questions/tagged/django) « [django-models](/questions/tagged/django-models) and [django-templates](/questions/tagged/django-templates) « [url-tag](/questions/tagged/url-tag) tag synonyms are completely wrong since those pairings have only one common thing: *Framework itself*.

But real annoying thing is the date under **creator** column. There is a suggestion that was nearly 3.5 years old and its status is `pending`

Do I have a wrong feeling that they are waiting in the queue for that long or I understand something wrong?

**Update:** I am not talking about letting people easy-approve tag synonyms but cleaning pending suggestions. A tag synonym suggestion must not wait 3.5 years in queue for approval or rejection. Possible solutions might be:

- Auto reject a suggestion if there is no approve/reject vote in last x months/weeks.
- Able to flag synonym suggestions (because there are some *really* wrong suggestions), so mods can reject it.

**Update 2:** Maybe, a tag synonym queue may be added to review section that is visible for users with enough reputation and pending synonym requests may be listed there according to the users *tag-reputation*.

Answer (score 2):

I like the tag synonym review queue idea. However, it may be too complicated/heavy to implement, since you would need to calculate the set of synonym requests that a user can vote on each time that user visits the review page (or calculate it in advance for each user, and update it as part of the user tag score calculation script, which is already heavy).

Alternative suggestions :

1. Whenever a synonym request is suggested by a user, send a message to all users that have a high enough tag score to vote on that synonym.
2. Create a "pending synonym requests" page. Only when this page is clicked, it would produce a list of tag synonym requests that the user can vote on. Perhaps this page should be part of the 10k moderation tools (in order to reduce the amount of queries this feature would require).

Comment: I am talking about the second choice, there will be a link to tag-synonym suggestions with no indication tha shows if there is any in queue. User mus visit the related part to see if there exists any. that will decrease relaed DB calls and will no cost much for the DB.